# How can I install PS3 joypad in wireless - bluetooth- mode (Steam compatible)?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, bluetooth, gamepad, ps3

I can connect and use my PS3 pad with the USB wire without issues, and then using *xboxdrv* I'm able to fully use it as an xbox pad under Steam.

Only issue is that I'd like to use it as a wireless device.
I've got bluetooth enabled but I don't seem to be able to link it and use it neither wireless neither with *xboxdrv*.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (latest LTS).

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[QTSixA](http://qtsixa.sourceforge.net/) has Bluetooth support for PS3. There also have been a few patches for the Linux kernel a while back that should make it work out of the box without any extra drivers, that would however require a more current version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Which version should I wait for? Again for wireless mode...

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work with xboxdrv...So can't use with Steam in wireless mode.